What is the unit used for measuring metrics for an Azure sql database?
I am running a script to get back some metrics for an Azure sql database.
$metrics = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $databaseResourceId -MetricName "dtu_consumption_percent" -    StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-100) -EndTime (Get-Date) 
$sumOfAverages = 0
foreach ($metric in $metrics.Data) {  
     foreach ($data in $metric) {
         # Add the average value to the sum
         $sumOfAverages += $data.Average    
    }
}
$sumOfAverages

But when I get the $sumOfAverages it outputs a value of 880.75.
What is that value measured in? It is %, so 8.8075 % of the dtuis set on the database. So if the DTU is 200, then it only used 8% of it. Is that right?
I have run some scripts to get the value, but do I need the metric?

So if i have configured a database to have DTU 100 and when i look in the Azure portal under metrics for DTU Percentage and select Max, it gives me a value of 95%.  Does that mean that the dtu for the time period of Last 30 days has at any one time reach 95% of 100 ?

How many entries do you get in $metrics for dtu_consumption_percent? It sounds wrong that you just add them together. Thats not how percentages work. You would need to divide: $sumOfAverages / $metrics.Count  to get the average percentage

Yes, MAX means maximum value in that time frame. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-aggregation-explained#aggregation-types

So if i have a filter of lets say 2 months and get max , that would give the max it has ever reached and i can make a calculated decision about DTU ?

It will give you the max value over that time.


A DTU is a unit of measurement used to evaluate the performance of a service tier in Azure SQL Database.  It is a composite metric that takes into account several database characteristics.
Each service tier is assigned a specific number of DTUs, which provides a simple way to compare the performance level of one tier to another.  DTUs are a standardized way to measure and compare the performance of different service tiers in Azure SQL Database.

The value that you are trying to  retrieve, dtu_consumption_percent, represents the percentage of the total DTU used by your Azure SQL Database.
As you mentiond that Azure portal giveing a value of 95%.
If you have configured your Azure SQL Database with 100 DTUs and you see that the Max DTU percentage in the Azure portal shows 95% for a given time period (such as the last 30 days), it indicates that at some point during that time period, the DTU usage of your database reached 95% of the total available DTUs.
your database was operating at near maximum capacity during that time period, which could potentially impact its performance.
95% of 100 DTUs = 95 DTUs.

Sizes (P1 = 100 DTUs, or 200% of S2, P2 = 200 DTUs or 400% of S2).
You can get the DTU percentage:
SELECT end_time,   
  (SELECT Max(v)    
   FROM (VALUES (avg_cpu_percent), (avg_data_io_percent), 
(avg_log_write_percent)) AS    
   value(v)) AS [avg_DTU_percent]   
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats;  

Reference: sys.dm_db_resource_stats (Azure SQL Database)
Compare vCore and DTU-based purchasing models of Azure SQL Database

and the output of the select will give max dtu percentagae ? So if the avg_DTU_percent is 1.86 then i assume its using 1.86 % of the dtu   so if DTU is set at 200 i used (1.86/100 X 200 = 3.72)  ..    what does that all mean as a measurable value ?  I mean i get 3.72 thats fine but of what ?  Old school taks manager show 60% cpu ewtc .....Also  dtu is a mix of cpu , memory , read / writes , so how can i pin point what is the issue , cpu or memory etc ?
